# LNCS style and proper handling of e-mails

Tags: lncs

When defining title in [LNCS](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) styled paper, one defined author list and links it to the institute list -- yet only one `\email` clause can be made per institute. Now, the docs are seemingly silent about the situation when there are few authors from one institute that want to have their e-mails visible.
When looking at papers made with llncs, this is usually handled with curly bracket, like this

> {J.Smith,J.Doe}@someinst.something

Now the question; I'm curious if there exist any more proper way of doing it on LaTeX level than just putting such string into `\email`?

Comment: With such styles it is very good to add a link, so that people which don't know it yet can also help you. I think you mean Springer's [Lecture Notes in Computer Science](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0), don't you?

Comment: @Martin I assumed it was obvious; fixed.

Comment: I don't think it is obvious to anyone outside of computer science.

Comment: @Caramdir I've got an impression that most Springer-based conferences use it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but for a recent `llncs`-based paper I used something like

```
\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\mailsa}\path|author1@someinst.something|
\urldef{\mailsb}\path|author2@someotherinst.something|
```

in the preamble, and after the `mainmatter`, the `institute` commands reads

```
\institute{affiliation goes here\\ \mailsa\\ \mailsb}
```

Answer (score 0):

I happily use `\email{my.self,my.boss@university.edu}` here. Afaik, this is the default, although I've seen `\email{my.self | my.boss@university.edu}` as well.